How can I configure isc-dhcp-client differently according to the chosen logical interface?
I am using debian ifupdown’s mappings, with guessnet, to connect to the “right” WiFi network wherever I am. Here is an excerpt of my /etc/network/interface:
mapping wlp2s0
        script /usr/sbin/guessnet-ifupdown
        map autofilter: true
        map default: wlp2s0-default

iface wlp2s0-tgv-inoui inet dhcp
        guessnet test wireless essid _SNCF_WIFI_INOUI
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_minimal.conf
        wpa-driver nl80211,wext
        wpa-ssid _SNCF_WIFI_INOUI
        wpa-key-mgmt NONE
        openvpn home_client

I also use unbound as a local caching DNS resolver.
When I am connected to the _SNCF_WIFI_INOUI WiFi network, I’d like to forward DNS requests for the sncf. zones to the resolver provided by the DHCP server, since it provides different answers from the public servers (which I need to get the information specific to the train I am traveling in).
As far as I know, isc-dhcp-client uses hooks that can be called when it gets answers for the DHCP server. I guess I could write one to configure unbound as needed.
But how can I ensure this only happens for the wlp2s0-tgv-inoui logical interface? Is there a way I can get the logical interface when running the hook?

Assuming you're using Debian 12, the isc-dhcp-client is the package name for dhclient.
The hook scripts will get a number of environment variables containing information about things like the name and type of the interface being configured ($interface and $medium respectively), received network parameters and DHCP options, and the type of DHCP operation ($reason).
See man dhclient-script and man dhcp-options for variable names. Also, make /etc/dhcp/debug executable, and then run ifdown+ifup for your network interface to get a listing of actual variables available in each step in /tmp/dhclient-script.debug. The contents of the dhclient-script.debug file should be very useful in writing your own hook script.
If none of the variables can be used, peeking into /run/network/ifstate and/or /run/network/ifstate.wlp2s0 might allow you to identify the selected mapping, if I remember correctly how the ifupdown mappings work.
There should be a line like wlp2s0=wlp2s0-tgv-inoui in one or both of those files, identifying the currently active mapping.

I’m currently still using Debian 11 but switching to Debian 12 should be an option. Anyhow, I tried to enable /etc/dhcp/debug. I have no $medium variable (I guess it may be Debian 12-specific). I have a $interface variable which gives the name of the physical interface (wlp2s0), which is close to useless for me, but no variable gives the name of the logical ifupdown (wlp2s0-tgv-inoui) interface. Am I missing something?

I used to have something similar once upon a time, but I've since migrated to NetworkManager on systems roaming between wireless networks, for the simple reason that it was designed to solve problems just like that. But see my edit above, assuming my memory is correct...

Thanks for the suggestion to peek into /run/network/ifstate.wlp2s0, that looks like what I was looking for! I feel stupid now for not thinking about that…
